# How can I combine jars using Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3

**The following snippet creates 2 JARS:**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-dependency</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>dependency</classifier>
                <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}\dependency</classesDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>${dependancyInclude}</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>module</classifier>
                <classesDirectory>${project.build.directory}\classes</classesDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**I would like to combine these two JARs into one using the assembly plugin, currently I have the following:**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <!-- Combine all the JARs in the /target folder into one JAR -->
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <attach>true</attach>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Currently only one of the two JARS in included in the final JAR that is created by the assembly plugin.**

Comment: Any specific reasons why you want to do that? In general, the rule is that you should have one artifact per project. Why are you first creating two artifacts and then combining them again into one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you actually want to merge the jar files into one big jar file. This can be achieved using the maven-shade-plugin (instead of the maven-assembly-plugin).

For example:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <configuration>
           <!-- Put your configuration here, if you need any extra settings.
                (You should be okay with the defaults). -->
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```